# C: Are structs implemented as pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Okay, I've searched around the other questions with similar names here, but no dice.

My question: Say we have a struct and an array of said struct:

```
typedef struct derp {
    int herp;
    double schlerp;
} struct_t;
struct_t* dynamic_array = (struct_t*)calloc(my_array_size, sizeof(struct_t));
```

Are structs implemented as pointers? Meaning, how does the following behave?

```
struct_t me;
me = dynamic_array[complicated calculation best not repeated];
me.herp += 2; //pretend it's properly initialized
me.schlerp *= 2; //ditto
```

Would the entry in that array show the changes to the struct members? I.e. is the `me` a deep copy of the array's struct's members, or merely a "pointer" of somesort to the same members as pointed to by the array?

I apologize if the question isn't making much sense, I'm trying to word it in more ways than one to minimize miscommunication. (Here's hoping that doesn't backfire :P)

Comment: Structs are structs, arrays are arrays, and pointers are pointers. None is *implemented as* any of the others, much like a pear isn't implemented as an apple.

Comment: Have you tried running your code to check whether the contents of the array are changed after changing `me`?

Comment: Structs behave as values, not as references (pointers in C). But as Justin said you can make them behave as references by using pointers to the struct.

Comment: Why was this closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not implemented as pointers.

when you use the subscript operator  `[]` on a pointer, it is interpreted as requesting the element at that position. so the compiler is simply able to determine the offset because the size of  the struct is known/constant.

```
// creates a new struct on the stack:
struct_t me;
// copies from dynamic_array[idx] to me
me = dynamic_array[idx];
```

> Would the entry in that array show the changes to the struct members?

no - `me` is a copy.

> I.e. is the me a deep copy of the array's struct's members, or merely a "pointer" of somesort to the same members as pointed to by the array?

if you want to alter the original, you can either reassign the struct:

```
dynamic_array[idx] = me;
```

or just work with a pointer to the struct to mutate:

```
struct_t* const me = &dynamic_array[idx];
me->herp += 2;
```

Comment: Okay, but if I then do `me.schlerp *= 2;`, would `dyn_array[idx]` show the new value or the old?

Comment: So it is a deep copy then? The take away being: be careful about assigning structs willy nilly, especially large structs... (in my actual use case, the struct contains a large array; and I have been using pointers anyways `me = dyn_array + idx` etc, but just wanted to know about this case).

Comment: @Dubslow if you have a field which is a *pointer*, then the *pointer* is assigned/copied. what it *points to* would not be copied. so yes, it is deep, with that exception.

Comment: See, this is why I ask other people, to catch stupid mistakes... thanks :). (Perhaps it's the problem with being equally proficient in Python and C, and splitting my time between them...)

Answer (score 3):

`me` is a *shallow* copy of the data in the array. Changing the members in `me` does not alter what's in the array. If the structure contains a pointer (a `char *` for example) then what it points to is not copied, just the pointer value, so modifying a deferenced pointer will affect the dereferenced value of the array entry as well (did that make sense?)

Comment: That's a contradiction. If it's a shallow copy, then the changes would alter what's in the array. If it's a deep copy, then the changes won't show up in the array.

Comment: @Dubslow it's a shallow copy.  If the changes altered the array that would be a reference.

Comment: @Dubslow: A shallow copy just copies the data in the array byte for byte. A deep copy creates copies of items the structure might be pointing to. In C, you can only do a deep copy by writing a copy function, in C++ you write a copy constructor / assignment overload.

Comment: @Dubslow With that logic, code such as `int a=1, b; b = a; b = 3;` should set `a` to 3, since `b` is a shallow copy *just like the case with a `struct`*? That doesn't make sense. A copy is a *copy*, it doesn't know anything about the original, or affect it in any way.

Comment: No, `b=a` is a deep copy. I think we're using different definitions. In this case, even though `b=a`, they "point" to different things (they have different locations in memory). That's why I say `me` is a deep copy -- instead of just pointing to the data in the array, `me` has its own separate (deep) copy of the data in the array.

Comment: See: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/, wikipedia is a bit confusing as it's OO centric: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy

Answer (score 1):

A struct is a description or a template that the compiler uses to determine the offset from the beginning of a memory area where the struct begins to the various members of the struct.

If you create a single, non-array variable using a struct, the compiler will allocate memory for that variable.  The amount of the memory will depend on the size of the struct which in turn depends on the types of the members of the struct.

An array that is defined using a struct is an array of individual struct members.  When you access an array element, the compiler figures a memory offset based on the the array index used and the size of the struct.

A struct has behavior similar to a built in type such as an int.  You can declare an int or a struct, an array of int or a struct, or a pointer to an int or a struct.

The main difference between an int and a struct is that the int is a built in type where as a struct is created and described by the programmer as a new type.

However I have found that it is most helpful to think of all data types, built in or specified by the programmer, as being a template for a memory area that the compiler uses to keep up with the address of the memory area, the type of the memory area, the size of the memory area, and what actions are allowed on the memory area.

The important point of this is that when you do assignment in C, think of it as being a copy of one memory area to another without any intelligence other than what would be from using a `memcpy()` function to do the same memory copy.  So when a struct variable containing a pointer is assigned to another struct variable both struct variables will have the same pointer, pointing to the same memory region.

However the basics of assignment, pointer calculations, and other behaviors are very similar between struc and built in types.

```
typedef struct {
   int iValue;
   int jValue;
} MyStruct;

{
   int   iLoneInt, jLoneInt;
   int  *piLoneInt;
   MyStruct  aStruct, bStruct;
   MyStruct  *paStruct;

   // simple assignment
   iLoneInt = 1;
   aStruct.iValue = 1;    // specify the struct member

   // assignment of one variable to another
   bStruct = aStruct;    // copies the value in memory region aStruct to bStruct
   jLoneInt = iLoneInt;  // copies the value in memory region iLoneInt to jLoneInt
   memcpy (&bStruct, &aStruct, sizeof(MyStruct));  // same as assignment
   memcpy (&jLoneInt, &iLoneInt, sizeof(int));  // same as assignment

   piLoneInt = &iLoneInt;   // gets address of memory region iLoneInt
   paStruct = &aStruct;     // gets address of memory region aStruct

   jLoneInt = *piLoneInt;   // copies value in memory region pointed to by piLineInt to jLoneInt
   bStruct = *paStruct;    // copies value in memory region pointed to by paStruct to bStruct
   memcpy (&bStruct, paStruct, sizeof(MyStruct));  // same as assignment
```